# RStudio's embedded browser is not saving cookies

Tags: shiny, rstudio

In the Shiny app I'm developing, one step requires logging to a remote server to browse files. The authentication procedure is designed so, that upon successful login, the sever responds with an authorization token and a cookie with session id. Both of them are required to be passed when performing subsequent requests to the server.

When testing the app in Chrome, everything works smoothly. When trying to use it in RStudio, where it's rendered with RStudio's embedded browser, the user is logged out immediately after a successful login with error message saying that user session has expired.

I have discovered that the root of the problem is that the RStudio's embedded browser is not saving the cookie with session ID. The storage tab in the inspector is empty.

[image: View of RStudio's embedded browser's inspector's storage tab]

Is there a way to change the RStudio's default browser or may there be a glitch in my thinking?

Comment: Please don't cross-post (or at least make it clear when you do so): https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudios-embedded-browser-is-not-saving-cookies/24426/2

Answer (score 0):

[I have been informed](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudios-embedded-browser-is-not-saving-cookies/24426) that to overcome this issue one has to download the [preview release (1.2)](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) of RStudio, which uses Chromium under the hood. It solved the problem in my case.